How i can change color or remove the default lines from my installer using Qt Installer Framework
The Qt installer Framework have a default gray lines top and bottom of page.
Example here:

I need to remove or colorize this lines for my styled installer. I was tried it using QSS (Qt Css) but .QFrame[frameShape="4"] is not work.
Version: QtInstallerFramework: 4.7
Somebody have any ideas how I can hide default lines from installer ?

You should use the enum name, not its value; try with: .QFrame[frameShape="HLine"]

Unfortunately, but HLine is not working too...
I think this lines draws using QPallete here, If is it true then change it will be very hard ...

Well, I'm not familiar with QtInstallerFramework. But if that was a standard QApplication dealing with a QWizard setup, I'd install an event filter for QWizardPages child events and then check for any QMetaObject based on QWizardHeader, then a related event filter would take care of Paint events and just ignore them to begin with.

Hm, seems as great idea, I was begun to rewrite qifw source code for adding supports missed functions, probably I try to add your suggestion.
